# What are the most useful and useless metrics to track in SEO?

Tags: seo

For example, <strike>PageRank</strike> (or not)... :-) ...question, still stands, just no example now.

Factors include how actionable it is, consistency of availability, or correlation to ranking.

Comment: PageRank is not useless. It is very misunderstood.

Comment: This is a Community Wiki question.

Comment: @BenV: Yes, it is, since it's a "List of XYZ" question.

Comment: So go ahead and change it :)

Comment: It is now community wiki :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USEFUL:

Incoming link quality, links from high trustrank and pagerank pages with relevant content and keyword in anchor text. sans nofollow.

Unique non duplicate content, especially unique title and description meta tags. And sane keyword density in text, so text is not considered spam.

USELESS:

Position in SEM results, a myth many believe in us that appearing on AdWords affects your ranking.

Answer (score 0):

**USEFUL:** Keyword Rank

Answer (score 0):

Useless: Alexa Page Rank